# Automatic 'like' after logging in via Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, access-token

I've been googling for days. I have a read a lot of documentation, forums etc, but I haven't found a working solution.
I am trying to add 'like' to the page https://www.facebook.com/Superawesometest on behalf of the user after he/she has logged in via facebook. I recieve all the necessarry permissions and an access_token.
but using `$facebook->api("/Superawesometest/likes", 'post');` wouldn't work
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Superawesometest page's Page ID instead of the name "Superawesometest" in the API path